# Do creatures that fall from the removal of a stone bridge created by a wall of stone spell get a save?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

[Wall of stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone) Says:

> The wall can have any shape you desire, though it can't occupy the same space as a creature or object. The wall doesn't need to be vertical or rest on any firm foundation. It must, however, merge with and be solidly supported by existing stone. Thus, **you can use this spell to bridge a chasm or create a ramp.**

If I make a bridge over a chasm, then ready an action to end my concentration when someone crosses it. Do the creatures who were on the wall get any kind of saving throw?  Or do they simply fall?

Comment: Related: "[When exactly can a caster stop concentrating on a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139537)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### It's up to the DM.

In the absence of a rule or feature calling for a saving throw, the DM decides if a circumstance calls for a saving throw. From the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, ["Saving Throws"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#SavingThrows):

> Most of the time, a saving throw comes into play when an effect — such as a spell, monster ability, or trap — calls for it, telling you what kind of saving throw is involved and providing a DC for it.
>
> Other times, a situation arises that clearly calls for a saving throw, especially when a character is subjected to a harmful effect that can’t be hedged out by armor or a shield. It’s up to you to decide which ability score is involved. The Saving Throws table offers suggestions.

The DM will decide if the particular situation merits a saving throw, and what the results of success and failure look like. For me, the creature's position on the bridge matters. Are they close to the end of the bridge? Probably saving throw. Are they in the middle of the bridge with nothing around to grab onto? Probably just fall damage. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Whether the enemy is aware that the bridge is magical matters too - one that saw you cast it or is aware that normally there isn't a bridge there may be more prepared to take action than one that is completely oblivious to the possibility that a stone bridge will instantaneously disappear.

Comment: Also, while you can drop concentration at any point, turns are abstractions of a continuous process.  You dropping concentration when they are "at the middle of the bridge" if they are actively crossing it is as much a matter of fine timing as "swinging a sword when someone's arm is right there".